# SP.ClientContext is undefined in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, jquery, jsom

I am trying to get details of logged In user through JSOM in SharePoint online.

Below is the code which I am trying:

```
SP.SOD.registerSod('sp.js', "/_layouts/15/sp.js");
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getCurrentUser);

function getCurrentUser() {
    try {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var tempcurrentUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        clientContext.load(tempcurrentUser);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            prf.loggedUser = tempcurrentUser.get_id();
            var userAcc = tempcurrentUser.get_loginName();                
        }, queryFailure);
    }
    catch (err) {
        queryFailure();
    }
}

function queryFailure() {
    alert('Error while accessing Active Directory');
}
```

In above code when I am trying to access ***SP.ClientContext.get_current()***, I am getting error stating SP.ClientContext is undefined.

I am new to SharePoint online, this question may be sound easy but I am open to learn.

Note: Above code is working fine in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use `_spPageContextInfo` object. You can directly get `Login Name` and `Login ID` of current logged user.

Refer below code:

`_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName`  => To get the Login Name

`_spPageContextInfo.userId` => To get the user ID

Again if you want to know more about what all other properties you can access using `_spPageContextInfo`, try to use this variable in console and you will see all the info that you can access directly.

Refer this link for more information: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29766.sharepoint-understanding-the-sppagecontextinfo-object.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing the document.ready() function?

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
 SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getCurrentUser);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/utilities/SPGetCurrentUser.html) method to get current user information in SPO.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
alert($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "Name",debug: false}));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing against Marc's library(SPServices) but suggesting a third party lib when there are easy out-of-the-box options available is wrong.